# javascript: character key of special characters created by alt+numpad

Tags: javascript, special-characters

When I hit alt + 6(Numpad keys) the character created is ♠, charCode=9824 but not 6. Is there a simple way to convert characters created this way(alt + Numpad keys 1-32) back to their Numpad key value (6 in this case) ?

Edit:
What I'm looking for is a simple way to filter out alt+Numpad characters in my input fields. The straightforward way of having a blacklist of 32 characters seems inefficient for long strings. Is there a way to treat them as a range?

Comment: The character for which the ASCII code is 6 is an ACK, which isn't even a printable character. The spade character doesn't appear in ASCII or extended ASCII.

Comment: I'm confused - what has ASCII got to do with pressing Alt-6 ?

Comment: This is a bit more complex than that. One thing is the keyboard mapping; one thing is the number of the character in whichever character set you are using. Please add more detail, what you need this for etc. @James he probably means the character key, the question has nothing to do with ASCII.

Answer (score 1):

This might help you: http://www.irongeek.com/alt-numpad-ascii-key-combos-and-chart.html